# Errors when trying to integrate Wordpress on my existing website

Tags: php, wordpress

I followed this guide from Wordpress Codex: [Integrating Wordpress with Your Website](http://codex.wordpress.org/Integrating_WordPress_with_Your_Website)
but I'm getting the following errors:

```
Declaration of Walker_Page::start_lvl() should be compatible with that of Walker::start_lvl() [ On E:\Documents\work\devenv\xampp\htdocs\orp\blog\wp-includes\post-template.php Line 1071 ]
Declaration of Walker_Page::end_lvl() should be compatible with that of Walker::end_lvl() [ On E:\Documents\work\devenv\xampp\htdocs\orp\blog\wp-includes\post-template.php Line 1071 ]
Declaration of Walker_Page::start_el() should be compatible with that of Walker::start_el() [ On E:\Documents\work\devenv\xampp\htdocs\orp\blog\wp-includes\post-template.php Line 1071 ]
Declaration of Walker_Page::end_el() should be compatible with that of Walker::end_el() [ On E:\Documents\work\devenv\xampp\htdocs\orp\blog\wp-includes\post-template.php Line 1071 ]
Declaration of Walker_PageDropdown::start_el() should be compatible with that of Walker::start_el() [ On E:\Documents\work\devenv\xampp\htdocs\orp\blog\wp-includes\post-template.php Line 1116 ]
Declaration of Walker_Category::start_lvl() should be compatible with that of Walker::start_lvl() [ On E:\Documents\work\devenv\xampp\htdocs\orp\blog\wp-includes\category-template.php Line 915 ]
Declaration of Walker_Category::end_lvl() should be compatible with that of Walker::end_lvl() [ On E:\Documents\work\devenv\xampp\htdocs\orp\blog\wp-includes\category-template.php Line 915 ]
Declaration of Walker_Category::start_el() should be compatible with that of Walker::start_el() [ On E:\Documents\work\devenv\xampp\htdocs\orp\blog\wp-includes\category-template.php Line 915 ]
Declaration of Walker_Category::end_el() should be compatible with that of Walker::end_el() [ On E:\Documents\work\devenv\xampp\htdocs\orp\blog\wp-includes\category-template.php Line 915 ]
Declaration of Walker_CategoryDropdown::start_el() should be compatible with that of Walker::start_el() [ On E:\Documents\work\devenv\xampp\htdocs\orp\blog\wp-includes\category-template.php Line 966 ]
Declaration of Walker_Comment::start_lvl() should be compatible with that of Walker::start_lvl() [ On E:\Documents\work\devenv\xampp\htdocs\orp\blog\wp-includes\comment-template.php Line 1400 ]
Declaration of Walker_Comment::end_lvl() should be compatible with that of Walker::end_lvl() [ On E:\Documents\work\devenv\xampp\htdocs\orp\blog\wp-includes\comment-template.php Line 1400 ]
Declaration of Walker_Comment::start_el() should be compatible with that of Walker::start_el() [ On E:\Documents\work\devenv\xampp\htdocs\orp\blog\wp-includes\comment-template.php Line 1400 ]
Declaration of Walker_Comment::end_el() should be compatible with that of Walker::end_el() [ On E:\Documents\work\devenv\xampp\htdocs\orp\blog\wp-includes\comment-template.php Line 1400 ]
Redefining already defined constructor for class WP_Widget [ On E:\Documents\work\devenv\xampp\htdocs\orp\blog\wp-includes\widgets.php Line 93 ]
Declaration of Walker_Nav_Menu::start_lvl() should be compatible with that of Walker::start_lvl() [ On E:\Documents\work\devenv\xampp\htdocs\orp\blog\wp-includes\nav-menu-template.php Line 109 ]
Declaration of Walker_Nav_Menu::end_lvl() should be compatible with that of Walker::end_lvl() [ On E:\Documents\work\devenv\xampp\htdocs\orp\blog\wp-includes\nav-menu-template.php Line 109 ]
Declaration of Walker_Nav_Menu::start_el() should be compatible with that of Walker::start_el() [ On E:\Documents\work\devenv\xampp\htdocs\orp\blog\wp-includes\nav-menu-template.php Line 109 ]
Declaration of Walker_Nav_Menu::end_el() should be compatible with that of Walker::end_el() [ On E:\Documents\work\devenv\xampp\htdocs\orp\blog\wp-includes\nav-menu-template.php Line 109 ]
Fatal error: Call to a member function add_rewrite_tag() on a non-object in E:\Documents\work\devenv\xampp\htdocs\orp\blog\wp-includes\taxonomy.php on line 333
```

Quite a mouthfull of errors! I'm on Wordpress v3.3.1 and PHP v5.3.1
My php.ini error reporting is `error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT`, but not sure if error_reporting is getting override somewhere in the code.

I poked around the Wordpress php files and saw the function arguments mismatching issue in `wp-includes/class-wp-walker.php`, but I don't want to just hotfix it by matching the arguments, without knowing the real issue.

Do you have any clue what might be going on here?

Thanks a lot!

**EDIT:** Fixed all the Declaration errors, now just one remains

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function add_rewrite_tag() on a non-object in E:\Documents\work\devenv\xampp\htdocs\orp\blog\wp-includes\taxonomy.php on line 334
```

It seems `$wp_rewrite` is not getting defined and its value is *null*. In fact all global variables are not availble inside `wp-includes\taxonomy.php`

Comment: Maybe take a look at this post on wordpress.org? http://wordpress.org/support/topic/cant-get-it-to-install-errors

Comment: How did you fix all the Declaration errors?

Answer (score 2):

Many of the errors (the "Declaration of X should be compatible") are actually warnings triggered by php's E_STRICT, which appears to be enabled regardless.

The last one appears to be wordpress trying to load some value to it's taxonomy class, which deals with URL rewriting and search-engine friendly URLs, but that fails or is not properly configured.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I moved the initialization code at the top of the script.

```
<?php 
  /* Short and sweet */
  define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
  require('./wp-blog-header.php');
?>
```

That solved it!

Thanks